# How to run specific tasks parallel in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have issues with some plugins not working properly when running Gradle with `--parallel` switch. Still, I would love to run at least the compilation and unit tests in parallel. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to specify which specific tasks can be executed in parallel.

In the Gradle build itself we hit issues with uploadArchives tasks not working properly with `--parallel`. At https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/gradle/fix-GRADLE-2492.gradle you can see how we fixed it using locks.

Comment: did you try this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html ?

Comment: we faced the same problem and temporaly disabled parallel execution, I just wonder which of the solutions to use. Why didnt you apply new maven task?